# Imagemagick – Converting portrait and landscape images to the largest size

Tags: image, terminal, imagemagick, mogrify

I have large portrait and landscape images. For example: 5000x3000 pixels and 2000x8000 pixels.

I want to scale them down to 502 pixels, keeping the aspect ratio, despite their orientation, so the largest size of all images will always be 502 pixels.

I found these lines on Stack Overflow, that were supposed to do the job

```
find . -type f -exec convert {} -resize "502>" {} \;
```

or

```
find ./*.jpeg -exec convert {} -resize "502>" {} \;
```

I type them and the console freezes. Nothing happens.

I know that there is a command to do that with `convert` or `mogrify`, cause I did it in the past, but I cannot remember the command line now.

I want to discover a way to do it thru terminal.

I am on macOS Sonoma.

Comment: Try `find . -type f -iname "*.jpg" -exec ...` to only convert things that a) are files and b) end case-insensitively in `.jpg`

Comment: If the files are all in one directory, you don't need `find` you can simply use `mogrify`, e.g. `magick mogrify -resize '502>' *.jpg`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the files are all in one directory, you don't need `find` you can simply use `mogrify`, e.g.

```
magick mogrify -resize '502>' *.jpg
```